# How does a self-balancing motorcycle BMW Vision Next 100 balance?

Tags: electrical-engineering

BMW unveils new self-balancing electric motorcycle concept.
And this concept can balancing itself.
How the balancing technology works?

Comment: How is this about physics? VTC as off topic

Comment: Just to clarify my close vote. We have to have establish a cutoff point for questions such as yours, even though everything based around the bike can be traced back to some  physics law or principle, it would take an engineer  to explain the relevant points more succinctly, imo

Answer (score 1):

CountTo10 has a good point.  There is physics involved but there are way better vehicles to get your answers.  Pun intended.  It's a combination of things that facilitate the self balancing effect.  It is a prototype and a really cool bike but it really is not a totally self balancing machine in it's entirety. It has the wider tires, Gyroscopic technology at the wheel and programs to help facilitate the effect.  It's a prototype so you will play heck getting all the druthers on it and that is by design.  Similar technology used for an ICBM incorporated with the natural centripetal forces of a bike are employed.  Don't believe the hype on not needing a helmet though.  That will always be a good idea.  I want one too.

Comment: you mean have a Gyroscopic technology at the wheel?

Comment: @ user3809000  http://usdynamicscorp.com/literature/general/precision_instruments.pdf       Picture instead of a fin change on a missile to an angle change on a tire.